# JWT and loading data for current login user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

I'm encountering an issue in my application where I want to load all tasks that the current user created after login. My login code redirects to say /dashboard after successful login but how would I load all tasks assigned to the user. I'm using JWT. Do I use componentdidmount on the dashboard page and query the database when dashboard page loads? Any help is appreciated.

My frontend login page forwards to the dashboard if response from server is successful and I have the token and userID. Now on the frontend dashboard, how would automatically load the currently logged users data? I feel like I'm missing something.

```
if (response.data) {
history.push("/dashboard");
}
```

Above is just snippet of the code on my React front end.

Answer (score 0):

If the API to fetch user tasks is on a different endpoint, then you can do 2 different things.

Either you use [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) or [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as a side effect to call that API and store it in redux. I assume you did the same thing for your JWT Token?

Or just use a normal [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hooks.

Here's the code that would achieve the same thing as `componentDidMount`

```
useEffect( () => { 
 async function getData(){ 
  fetchTasks();
 }
 getData()
, []}
```